# How to use cordova-sqlcipher-adapter with ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, sqlcipher

I have used the SQLite plugin listed on ionic 3 packages [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/sqlite/). But now  I want to store the data in an encrypted format. For that , I am trying to implement cordova-sqlcipher-adapter plugin but I am unable to get started as I am confused whether to use it with the SQLite plugin or use it as a standalone plugin for sqlite db operations? I have gone through the documentation but I am unable to get started.

Help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do following in order to use cordova-sqlcipher-adapter (it  works for me)

1. remove SQLite plugin (Keep SQLlite npm package, I have used SQLite4)
2. cordova plugin add cordova-sqlcipher-adapter
3. In app.modules.js

```js
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
...
providers: [
    ....
    SQLite,
```

Now, use below to create db and use it

```js
var db = (<any>window).sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
  name: 'demo.db',
  key: 'secret-key',
  location: 'default'
});
```

And [Follow link](https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlcipher-adapter#sample) for other db opertations